# Which is the International Airport in Johannesburg?

Tags: air-travel, airports, johannesburg

There seem to be two airports :

- Johannesburg International,South Africa [JNB]

and

- Johannesburg Grand Central,South Africa [GCJ]

Is there a difference between the two? I'll be traveling from India to South Africa, first timer so confused about the two airports.

Comment: Welcome to the site, good question but I would edit out the parts about "better and safer" because those are mostly subjective criteria

Comment: "Grand Central Airport (IATA: GCJ, ICAO: FAGC) is a small privately owned airfield which is open to public air traffic." I've lived in Johannesburg and had never heard of it before now. It is for light aircraft only, and there are no scheduled commercial flights to or from it, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Johannesburg's main airport is 'ORT', [O.R. Tambo International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O._R._Tambo_International_Airport). The IATA code for ORT is JNB.

Jo'burg's secondary airport is [Lanseria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanseria_International_Airport). Apparently, it's calling itself 'international', but I'm not quite sure there are actually international flights coming or going here. It *is* used by two budget carriers, though.

Between the two, there is no real alternative when coming from abroad. You will arrive at ORT. I've flown a dozen times or more to ORT and would say it's safe. Beware of taxi drivers, though. They are, like perhaps everywhere else, notorious for trying to pull a fast one.

Depending on where you need to go, your best bet is probably to take the [Gautrain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautrain) to either Johannesburg or Pretoria.

Comment: The IATA code for O. R. Tambo airport is JNB.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I put ORT in quotes.

Comment: In terms of transport, quite a lot of accommodation will organise transport for you too (at a reasonable price). It doesn't hurt to ask and can make it a hell of a lot less daunting arriving to find someone with a board with your name on it as you leave the luggage hall compared to trying to work your way around a public transport network for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

Oliver Tambo ( formerly Jan Smuts ) is the airport that International ( intercontinental ) flights will use it is located about 50km East of central Johannesburg and has all the expected communications links. Grand Central is a smaller local field used mostly for general aviation movements it is north East of Johannesburg, South West of Pretoria located in an area called Midrand. Lanseria is North of Johannesburg. It has International status but services more flights from neighbouring states, freight and business jets etc.

One other major international airport is at Cape Town. approximately 1400 km South West of JHB. Major regional airports are at Bloemfontein and Durban with Durban servicing the Indian Ocean Islands, Far East and Australasia.

Comment: 50k is overstating it a bit: Parktown (in the center of JHB) to ORT can be as little as 25k: https://www.google.com.br/maps/dir/O.R.+Tambo+International+Airport,+Johannesburg,+South+Africa/Parktown,+Johannesburg,+2193,+South+Africa/@-26.171591,28.0640801,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x1e95143805a229c3:0xb3bf1c40792821d6!2m2!1d28.2411459!2d-26.1366728!1m5!1m1!1s0x1e950c6c5f840975:0xc9ab519ed580f7d0!2m2!1d28.0391009!2d-26.1806445?hl=en To/from downtown Pretoria is about 50k.

Comment: Yup It's only 25k. bad fingers! :)